# How to best hide a table column for mobile view

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a HTML table, in a mobile browser I need to hide some of its columns.

I want to  hide 2 or 3 of these cols using `@media` queries if possible.
the below code didn't work for me:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class='collapsable'></td>
      <td class='collapsable'></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>


      //hide cols here
      td.collapsable {display:block; }

      @media only screen and (min-width: 450px) {
           //show cols here
           td.collapsable {display:none; }
      }
```

Comment: Plan B: put a DIV in each cell. Class the DIVs by column. Hide the DIVs.

Comment: ok, I see where you're at. Yes if no one post a direct solution that actually collapses that will have to do :)

Comment: Should your media query be max-width if you are hiding the column for smaller displays?

Comment: im coding css for mobile first, then using media queries for desktop. My question was worded the other way around.

Comment: Mmm I've seen this a lot. Assign class to the part that may not be displayed. Gues what? You still request the data.... Just don't post data to the mobiles. Or you expect all users to have unlimited data limits??

Comment: @Bondye: I agree, it would be better if the mobile browser didn't have to request that data, but depending on the table size it might not be that big of an issue. The alternatives are UAS detection or JavaScript, which have their own problems.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Something like [this?](http://jsfiddle.net/j3VSN/1/) (try resizing the Result window/pane)

The HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td class="one">corpse</td>
    <td>corpse</td>
    <td>corpse</td>
</tr>
```

The CSS:

```
table{
        width: 50%;
    }
    td, th{
        border: 1px solid orange;
    }


    @media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
        .one{
            display: none;
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes the jsfiddle looks good. love it thankyou; exactly what I was looking for. No more JS :)

Comment: @IEnumerable isn't this exactly what you had written in your question?

Comment: Oh I see, it's effectively the opposite of what you did.

Comment: thats one way to get rid of a corpse

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem but I also added CSS style display:block; for class .one outside of the @media to make it visible again on all other screen sizes, but apparently that is not necessary.

Answer (score 14):

Keep your HTML and table markup clean by using nth-child to hide the column. Should work with every modern browser that supports media queries.

Here's a sample fiddle showing it in action. Resize the result pane to see it work.

https://jsfiddle.net/tycahill/xm0nwr7x

The *clean* HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Column 1a</td>
    <td>Column 2a</td>
    <td>Column 3a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Column 1b</td>
    <td>Column 2b</td>
    <td>Column 3b</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The CSS to hide the second column:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  td:nth-child(2) {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Plan B: put a DIV in each cell. Class the DIVs by column. Hide the DIVs. You may need to adjust your table's cellpadding/cellspacing and put it on the `.cell` DIV to maintain the previous appearance.

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td><div class='cell'></div></td>
      <td><div class='cell collapsable'></div></td>
      <td><div class='cell collapsable'></div></td>
      <td><div class='cell'></div></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: good work with the .cell - I just tried it out and worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I think your example has the `display:block` and `display:none` switched. Also, I would recommend using `display: table-cell;` instead of `display: block;`, since table-cell is the default display for `<td>` elements.  This CSS worked for me, and also is a mobile-first approach:

```
td.collapsable {display:none; }

@media only screen and (min-width: 450px) {
  td.collapsable {display:table-cell; }
}
```

Comment: Im having trouble making this work, do I apply the class to just the th or each td as well ?

Comment: I applied it to only the td. Maybe it's a browser-specific issue; have you tested in other browsers?